# Editing in Pages is disabled for this site. Please contact your site administrator

Tags: xm-cloud

Somehow I got into this issues after running some cleanup database in Control Panel. Whenever I open any sites under pages.sitecorecloud.io, I always get this warning dialog "Editing in Pages is disabled for this site. Please contact your site administrator". Does anyone know how to resolve this? Everything was working fine before I perform clean up database. I'm currently using boilerplate from https://github.com/sitecorelabs/xmcloud-foundation-head and already have Admin role. Thank you so much